# ReactJS: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to convert the code from the `Add React in One Minute` guide (https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute) from class to function but I get the error message `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`:

```js
'use strict';

const Jobs = () => {
  
    const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <button <-- SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
            onClick={() => setLiked(true)}
        >
            {liked ? 'You liked' : 'Like'}
        </button>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(Jobs, document.getElementById("reactApp"));
```

Note, that I added the error and the issue to the code. In my app it is not there, for sure.

I am using CodeIgniter and this is my view:

```php
<div id="reactApp"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.js" crossorigin></script>-->

<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/jobs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? Did you run babel?

Comment: I updated the code. I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Try import React from 'react'

Comment: I am not familiar with CodeIgniter. But your code should be pre-processed by babel. It is not pure Javascript. I assume the error you see is for JavaScript files.
Maybe you need to change the file extension to jsx

Comment: the tutorial link in your question use `React.createElement` to create a `button`, and in your example, you are using the JSX syntax. Hence the difference. You will need to either follow the createElement way or use babel to process